# Knife ssh not loading environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, chef-infra, knife

On my node `node_name` I've got `$JAVA_HOME` and other environment variables set in `/etc/profile`. I'm aware (found that out) that `knife ssh` isn't a login shell, and so doesn't load the environment variables. Is there a way to load the environment variables without having to `source` it?
Right now I'm forced to do

```
knife ssh 'name:nod_name' 'source /etc/profile; echo $JAVA_HOME'
```

I'm chaining in a few commands during `knife ssh` including some of the environment variables and loading the `/etc/profile` just makes that longer. Is there a way to load the /etc/profile during knife ssh?

Comment: This is a issue with the remote node's shell configuration. If you SSH'ed into the remote node without knife you'd be facing the same problem.

Comment: How exactly do you fix the shell configuration of that node then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with knife ssh, it is just how SSH works for commands executed directly over a connection. You can alternatively run a command like `bash -l -c "something"`. In general you can't count on any specific way of setting env vars in non-interactive sessions as being portable, so caveat emptor.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the OP's question, but was searching for a solution to a similar problem.  Thought I would share my situation and solution to maybe help someone.  My issue was trying to run Chef remotely on our on-premise servers with awscli credentials in root's .bashrc. The `-i` switch was what I was missing in order to load root's environment variables in .bashrc.

Did not work:

`knife ssh "name:$NODE" "sudo /etc/init.d/appserver stop; sleep 10;sudo  chef-client -r role_appserver" -A -x user -P password`

Worked:

`knife ssh "name:$NODE" "sudo /etc/init.d/appserver stop; sleep 10;sudo -i chef-client -r role_appserver" -A -x user -P password`