# "sudo: chef-client: command not found" when executed with knife from workstation

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I have an issue with running chef-client on my nodes when I trigger chef-client using knife on my workstation. I am on macOS and my nodes are also macOS. In general, knife seems working for me because if I execute, for example, `knife ssh tags:my-mac-mini' 'pwd' -x ‘myUser’ -a ipaddress -P ‘myPasswrod’` it connects to the nodes tagged with `my-mac-mini` and then prints list of nodes with working directories. But when I try to execute `knife ssh tags:my-mac-mini' 'sudo chef-client' -x ‘myUser’ -a ipaddress -P ‘myPasswrod’`, it prints out `sudo: chef-client: command not found` for each node respectively. And moreover, my nodes are bootstrapped and I can run chef-client on all nodes when I am logged in to particular node.
I am quite sure I am missing something in my setup but I don't really get what can be wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Looks like `chef-client` is not installed on your node. You might have to install it using chefdk.

Comment: @bitsapien thanks for your reply. Unfortunately. it's not the case; my nodes are bootstrapped and I can run chef-client when on all nodes. Let me update the question with these detail

Comment: In that case, the shell in which your `knife` commands are being run is incorrect. I'd suggest you pass in the complete path of the chef-client binary. Should look something like `/usr/bin/chef-client`

Comment: @bitsapien do you mean to say, I need to specify path to chef-client on my nodes? let me try it out, although I am not sure if it is needed since I can execute just `sudo chef-client` on my nodes when I connect via ssh with the same credentials as in knife command

Comment: @olyv: if you are using chef rubygem and not chefdk, try to append `bundle exec` before the `knife` command and let us know whether it helps...

Comment: Hi @bitsapien, you are right, it works if i specify full path to chef-client binary. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25534357/2504101 also helped me. If you add an answer to my question, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if the shell in which you are running your command, does not have the specified binary in its path. You might have to specify the complete path to your binary.

Since you say that you can `ssh` into your node and run `chef-client`, run the below to grab the full path of the binary

```sh
$ which chef-client
```

The output of this would something like this

```
/path/to/chef-client
```

Now, use this full path instead of `chef-client` alone when running via `knife`